# Could we create an artificial metamorphosis on humans with genetic engineering?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, xenobiology, hard-science

I'm writting a hard-science book where adult humans with the help of  genetic engineering can undergo metamorphosis, could it be possible?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/233442/30492

Comment: By the way, reposting a question to circumvent a closure is not exactly appreciated

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the term "hard science", and not just as applies to this site.

Comment: If the reason you reposted is because you happened to have troubles finding your old question, know that you can look at all your posted questions on your profile... [Here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/97415/kaibarta?tab=questions)! Otherwise, if it's to improve your old question and get better answers, try to understand the issues of the old one (hopefully we were clear enough) and [edit it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/233442/could-metamorphosis-work-in-humans) :).

Comment: (a) If you read the mouse roll-over text for [tag:science-based] and [tag:hard-science] you will learn that *they are **mutually exclusive.*** (b) The [tag:hard-science] tag refers to the nature of answers on this site. It has little to do with the "hard science" genre of Science Fiction other than it demands (and I mean that, *demands*) that answers prove themselves correct with mathematics and citations to credible journals, etc. As a rule, if you don't have the ability to judge the answer to a [tag:hard-science] question, you should think long and hard about using the tag. It's ruthless.

Answer (score 0):

**Absolutely!**

Genetic engineering can effect the metamorphosis of sickly todders doomed to a short life of illness.  They can be transformed into normal healthy people!

[image: ashanti]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgES04-cSr8

https://www.ashclinicalnews.org/spotlight/feature-articles/gene-therapy-comeback-kid-hematology-treatments/

> Ashanthi de Silva was the first human to be treated successfully with
> gene therapy. At the time, in 1990, she was a 4-year-old living with
> severe combined immunodeficiency (SCID), which is caused by
> insufficient levels of the enzyme adenosine deaminase (ADA). Without
> treatment, patients rarely survive toddlerhood. In addition to
> hematopoietic cell transplantation, standard treatment at that time
> consisted of lifelong replacement with synthetic ADA given via
> intramuscular injections once or twice weekly. However, few patients
> achieve full immune reconstitution and improvements in immune function
> can wane in just a few years with enzyme replacement therapy. Turning
> to a cutting-edge treatment, scientists were able to deliver to
> Ashanthi a healthy version of the gene that produces ADA using a viral
> vector. She is still alive today.

She is the first but now there are many others, with a wide range of illnesses.  These inherited diseases are truly terrible.  The afflicted and their families suffer and suffer.  The prospect of a metamorphosis from a person with a genetic curse into a person without one is one of the most amazing metamorphoses I can imagine!